# What is the difference between standard and wild?

Tags: hearthstone

What are the differences between the 2 and what does *"all cards can be used"* mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard only allows you to use cards from the last two years and the Classic set. Every time the first set of a new year is released, the sets that are older than that are rotated out and can only be played in Wild.

Wild allows all cards ever released. This means currently in addition to the Classic set, only cards released in 2015 and 2016 are playable in Standard, resulting in cards from the "Naxxramas" adventure and "Goblins vs. Gnomes" expansion to be only allowed in Wild. When the first expansion of 2017 releases, "Blackrock Mountain", "The Grand Tournament" and "League of Explorers" cards will no longer be able to be played in Standard.

All this is explained in more detail here: http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505/a-new-way-to-play-2-2-2016

Answer (score 2):

If you are a new player, all the card packs and adventures you can purchase in the store (or get as tavern brawl or arena rewards), can be played in both Standard and in Wild.

Players who started in 2014 or earlier are likely to have cards that have been "rotated out" of both the store and from being allowed in Standard games.  The only way to get these older cards now is to craft them from dust.  In addition to all the Standard cards, these older cards are also allowed in Wild games.

Cards in the "Classic" set will always be part of Standard.

In the spring each year, older non-Classic card sets will be retired from Standard, removed from the store, and only allowed in Wild games moving forward.  So in Spring 2017, all the cards released in 2015 will be retired.  In Spring 2018, all the cards released in 2016 will be retired.  Etc.